# stringify function with function inside

Tags: javascript

is there any way to stringify function which has function inside? I want to stringify `bar` function.

```
const foo = (x) => {
  return x + x;
};
const bar = (y) => {
  return foo(y)
};
```

`bar.toString()` returns

```
function bar(y) {
  return foo(y);
}
```

but I want something like:

```
const bar = (y) => {
  const foo = (x) => {
    return x + x;
  };
  return foo(y);
};
```

Is it even possible? I want to use `bar` as follow:

```
// I don't have control below this line
import bar from 'bar';

`<script>(${bar})(5)</script>`
```

Comment: to achieve that you must do as `bar(5).toString()`

Comment: @Codenewbie - No, that won't work.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , why is that ? bar(5) -> gives 5  and then `toString` ? i have tried it

Comment: @Codenewbie - `"5"` isn't what the OP said they want.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder my bad !! okay does OP need that the function stringified ?

Comment: You could search the `bar` string for `foo` and replace that with `foo.toString()`...?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it even possible?

Probably. It is **not**, at all, simple. To do it, you'd have to use a JavaScript parser like Esprima or the ones in Babel, ESLint, etc. to parse the source code that contains both `bar` and `foo` and use the resulting AST to identify the functions that `bar` calls, convert those functions to source code, convert `bar` to source code, and insert the functions it calls into the beginning of it. And even then, depending on what *those* functions call and what things they use that they close over, you may have more work to do.

It's tempting to think "Well, I could just use `toString` on the functions and then a bit of regular expression to figure out what functions `bar` calls." But JavaScript source code syntax is far too complex to correctly identify function calls in a function's code with a regex or two. You need a proper parser.

As someone said in the comments (now deleted), this sounds like [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) — like you're trying to solve some other problem by doing this odd conversion of `bar`. I would focus on solving that problem a different way instead.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my xy problem comment because `// I don't have control below this line` suggests there might not be an alternate approach

Comment: @ChrisG - Yeah, I understand. I think there must be, but if there isn't, the parser approach is basically what they're stuck with. :-)